# How to print to 12.04 from Macbook

Tags: printing

I upgraded to 12.04 a few days ago and can no longer print to my shared printer (HP P1006) from my MacBook Pro (10.6).  I can print locally.  Printer sharing was working acceptably before the upgrade; it required identifying myself as "Guest" on every print request, but I could live with that.  Now I consistently get authentication rejections as either a registered user (registration defined in the Sambu GUI app), or as Guest.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Voting to close this unanswered question about EOL 12.04 as `not reproducible`. +1 to question though as OP is long standing member who returns to site often yet only has rep of 11 after 5+ years and Q&A only viewed by 394 people. *Give credit where credit is due*.